# Ckeditor edit problem - i cant show code snippets when edit

Tags: javascript, php, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x, ckeditor.net

I use **CKeditor** and i have a blog page. I create a kind of posts and sometimes share programming codes so i send to database this posts after retrieving from another page for edit. When I do this it happens as in the screenshot. How can i solve this ?

Example:

[picture-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soNCX.png)

[picture-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urJsY.png)

When transferring a post as source code and I want to edit it, I want it to look like it is